# Choosing a file in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Where is the tkFileDialog module in Python 3? The question [Choosing a file in Python with simple Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-simple-gui) references the module using:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
```

but using that (after changing Tkinter to tkinter) in Python 3 gets:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\me\My Documents\file.pyw", line 5, in <module>
    import tkFileDialog
ImportError: No module named tkFileDialog
```

The python 2.7.2 doc (docs.python.org) says:

```
tkFileDialog
Common dialogs to allow the user to specify a file to open or save.

These have been renamed as well in Python 3.0; they were all made submodules of the new tkinter package.
```

but it gives no hint what the new names would be, and searching for tkFileDialog and askopenfilename in the 3.2.2 docs returns nothing at all (not even a mapping from the old names to the new submodule names.)

Trying the obvious doesn't do jack:

```
from tkinter import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
ImportError: cannot import name askopenfilename
```

How do you call the equivalent of askopenfilename() in Python 3?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're looking for `tkinter.filedialog` as noted [in the docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.4/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules).

```
from tkinter import filedialog
```

You can look at what methods/classes are in `filedialog` by running `help(filedialog)` in the python interpreter.  I think `filedialog.LoadFileDialog` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 14):

You can try something like this:

```
from  tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "E:/Images",title = "choose your file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
print (root.filename)
root.withdraw()
```

Comment: `filedialog` isn't available via `from tkinter import *`. You have to do such as `from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename`.

Comment: I just added the root.withdraw() call, to remove the pesky window. 
My code worked fine in Python 3.4

Comment: Better to put `root.withdraw()` before  the call to the dialog box, otherwise it's present while the dialog box is open.