# Open a file browser in a specific folder with Python

Tags: python, explorer, blender, file-browser

I'm a french guy, so excuse me if my English is not very good.
Here is my problem : I'm using python to make a script that works with Blender, and I need to import an .obj file. I already have the importer, but I enter the entire filepath.

It's look like that :

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath='C:/Users/MarcPro/Desktop/testauto/03-Reconstruction/Data/Tile/Tile.obj', axis_forward='Y', axis_up='Z')
```

Instead, I would like to open a file browser (for example *explorer.exe*), go search for the .obj file and select it for bpy.ops.import_scene.obj importer.

Do you have any idea please ?

Thanks,

Ero.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a very Blender-friendly approach, in my opinion.

I think what you want to do is use the built-in Blender file selection dialog to pick the file.

I'm not sure, but this might be something for [`bpy.types.WindowManager.fileselect_add`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_66_4/bpy.types.WindowManager.html?highlight=file%20selector#bpy.types.WindowManager.fileselect_add).

Comment: I tried use bpy.types.WindowManager.fileselect_add but I don't understand how to correctly use it. It just opened the explorer. How can I open a directory, select the file and put its path into the filepath variable and then call bpy.ops.import_scene.ob ?

Comment: Actually I want to do the same thing that Tkinter does : show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file. Very simple with Tkinter, but I tried several with blender's python, I can't find the way to do it.

Answer (score -3):

You can choose a file in python using Tkinter: 
[Choosing a file in Python with simple Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-simple-gui)

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
print(filename)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to say that I already try to use Tkinter, but it's not working anymore on the lastest versions of Blender's python. But I can try it again to see what I get.

Comment: Actually I want to do the same thing that Tkinter does : show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file. Very simple with Tkinter, but I tried several with blender's python, I can't find the way to do it.