# Python Tkinter throwing Tcl error

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am learning basic GUI in Python, and I came across a sample example to read file name from file explorer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-with-simple-dialog%22Stackoverflow%22).

```
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file
print(filename)
```

This particular script is working fine when I am trying to run it in IDLE, but the same is not running if I am trying from command prompt in windows 7.

Python Version: 2.7. Here is the output error which I get.

```
>>> from Tkinter import Tk
>>> from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
>>> Tk().withdraw()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1685, in __init__
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
C:/Python27/lib/tcl8.5 D:/PyProj/lib/tcl8.5 D:/lib/tcl8.5 D:/PyProj/library D:/library D:/tcl8.5.2/library D:/tcl8.5.2/library

This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly
```

Any pointer to what I am missing here can be of great help.

Comment: Are you certain that the version of python you use in idle is the same version being used on the command line?

Comment: @BryanOakley yes I am using the same version. Here is a snippet of the same 

IDLE: Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Python CmdLine: Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 07:43:08) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Answer (score 20):

You just need to copy two folders from tcl folder to the Lib folder

tcl8.5 and tk8.5

Comment: This solved the problem for me. Windows 10, running Python in PowerShell, Python 3.6.3, tcl8.6, tk8.6. Got errors when trying to run matplotlib. After copying the folders it works. Thanks alot!

Comment: I also solved it by copying tcl8.6 and tk8.6  into the Lib folder on Python 3.8

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! It helped with my miniconda virtual env with Python 3.8 too!!

Answer (score 15):

In case you are using Virtualenv on Windows I found a solution here: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/93

I copied the "tcl" folder from C:\Python27\ over to the root of the new Virtualenv, Tkinter.Tk() shows a new window without throwing an exception.

I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 7):

Hit a similar problem after installing Activestate Python and TCL. I found the following page solved the problem for me: [ActiveState Python install problem](https://community.activestate.com/node/19090). The fix was to copy the contents of `C:\Python27\tcl` into `C:\Python27\Lib`.

Another potential solution (given by user i-shenl in a different [ActiveState thread](http://community.activestate.com/node/12746) on the same issue) is to set the [environment variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653.aspx) [`$TCL_LIBRARY`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1629) to point to the tcl library folder ("C:/Python27/tcl", in the question). If you set this system-wide or account-wide (via [System Properties](https://superuser.com/q/284342/7542)), it will affect other programs that use a TCL Library (if any are installed). If you're using Powershell, you can set this variable in your [profile](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488.aspx) to limit its affects to programs run from the shell.

Comment: Copying contents of that folder worked for me.  All files/folders in the tcl subfolder began with tk or tcl and none in the destination lib subfolder did - I checked that before I did the copy in case I wanted to back it out again!

Answer (score 4):

I hit the same problem on Ubuntu 17.04 with virtualenvwrapper for 64 bit Python 2.7

I add tk and tcl library paths in local [postactivate script](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts.html#postactivate)

1. Go to your virtualenv: `workon your-env-name`
2. Edit local postactiave script with your favourite editor, for ex:
   `gedit $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate`
3. Locate tk and tcl library paths. In postactivate script, export TK_LIBRARY and TCL_LIBRARY with appropriate paths. Add this lines to your script with modified paths:

   `TK_LIBRARY=/home/kamil/anaconda2/pkgs/tk-8.5
   TKPATH=/home/kamil/anaconda2/pkgs/tk-8.5
   TCL_LIBRARY=/home/kamil/anaconda2/lib/tcl8.5
   export TCL_LIBRARY TK_LIBRARY TKPATH`
4. Restart your virtualenv: `deactivate` and `workon your-env-name` again.

Answer (score 3):

If you are hitting this kind of error in a `python -m venv NAME` kind of virtual environment (and you actually have tcl installed in your system), then you need to export the paths similarly as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44699248/1169324) by Kamil Czerski in a previous post for virtualenv.

1. To find out what are your TK and TCL paths, run a python script **outside** of the venv ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43464686/1169324)):

> ```
> import tkinter
> root = tkinter.Tk()   
> print(root.tk.exprstring('$tcl_library'))   
> print(root.tk.exprstring('$tk_library'))
> ```

2. Open your venv configuration file `bin/activate` and find the place where they `export PATH` and insert after this (insert correct paths from step 1):

> ```
> TCL_LIBRARY="/tcl/path/from/step/1"   
> TK_LIBRARY="/tk/path/from/step/1"   
> TKPATH="/tk/path/from/step/1"  
> export TCL_LIBRARY TK_LIBRARY TKPATH
> ```

3. Deactivate (if it was activated) and source again your venv:

> ```
> deactivate  
> source bin/activate
> ```

The "Tcl missing"-error should be gone.

Answer (score 1):

Go to directory in which all of your python dependencies are stored

Example:

```
Python37 
  -DLLs
  -Doc
  -etc
  -include
  -Lib
  -libs
  -Scripts
  -tcl
  -python.exe
```

Go to tcl folder, copy the tcl8.5 and tk8.5 folder
Paste these folders in the Lib folder

This solution works for Windows 10 users

Answer (score 0):

IDLE is probably setting the path required for TCL. To find out what path is being used by IDLE, compare the output of sys.path from IDLE and without IDLE. Then you can add the location of init.tcl either using an environment variable or programatically. See Xenomorph suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is copy `tcl 8.6` and `tcl 8.5` from `tcl` file to `Lib` file on in `python`.
`Python-tcl-tcl8.5` to `Python-Lib`

Answer (score 0):

If you know you have TCL and TK installed, then try and search for the file(s) that are missing! E.g. in the error message it states that `init.tcl` file is missing from the expected paths/locations. But that file might be located elseware on the computer! If it does, copy the containing folder to the expected location for a quick fix.

You just need to copy two folders.

`tcl8.5` from the `Python/tcl/TCL8.5` folder - to the `Python/Lib/TCL8.5` folder. Do the same for `tk8.5` but use `Python/TK/tk8.5` folder - to the `Python/Lib/TKL8.5` folder.

You local pathing might be a bit different from the above. But that is the general idea.