# How to find the path of Tcl/Tk library that Tkinter is currently using?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

`TCL_LIBRARY` and `TK_LIBRARY` environment variables can be used to bind Tkinter with proper Tcl/Tk installation.

How to get the location of Tcl/Tk from working Tkinter instance?

(I'm running a frontend in non-virtual Python with working Tkinter and I need to run a tkinter subprocess in a virtual environment. Virtual Python doesn't find Tcl/Tk. I can specify `TCL_LIBRARY` and `TK_LIBRARY` manually, but I'd like to have more general solution and extract this information from the parent process.)

Answer (score 11):

Found the solution myself:

```
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()
print(root.tk.exprstring('$tcl_library'))
print(root.tk.exprstring('$tk_library'))
```