# tkinter can't find a usable init.tcl on spyder

Tags: python, tkinter

The tk module has problems doing just about anything, giving the error message:

```
TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories: 
/usr/local/Cellar/tcl-tk/8.6.13_4/lib/tcl8.6 /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/lib/tcl8.6 /Applications/Spyder.app/lib/tcl8.6 /Applications/Spyder.app/Contents/library /Applications/Spyder.app/library /Applications/Spyder.app/tcl8.6.13/library /Applications/tcl8.6.13/library 

This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

I re-downloaded Tcl and put the library in one of the directories it is looking for, as per the suggestions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320039/python-tkinter-throwing-tcl-error?rq=3). I also made sure that I have Tkinter working on my computer - running the command

```
python3 -m tkinter
```

launches the proper window, which also tells me that my version of tkinter is indeed 8.6.13, but working from Spyder yields the mentioned error message.

Comment: You need to upgrade Spyder 5