Matplotlib Plot Not Responding in VSCode Debug Mode
I'm encountering an issue when trying to plot a simple graph using Matplotlib in Python while in debug mode in VSCode. The plot works perfectly in normal execution mode, but when I set a breakpoint and run the code in debug mode, the plot window becomes unresponsive.
Example Code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [10, 20, 25, 30, 40]

# Plotting the data
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title('Sample Plot')
plt.xlabel('x-axis')
plt.ylabel('y-axis')

# Show plot
plt.show()

In normal execution mode, the plot window appears and is responsive.
In debug mode with a breakpoint, the plot window appears but becomes unresponsive and eventually throws a "not responding" error.

I tried using different Matplotlib backends, but none of them resolved the issue.
I expect to be able to plot graphs using Matplotlib in debug mode vscode without the plot window becoming unresponsive.

Can you try to add plt.pause(0.1)  # Add a small pause above plt.show()? By the way, Jupyter can run matplotlib perfectly.

I also had this issue. I got it working again by running Python 3.11.9 instead of 3.12.*, and I also had to switch to matplotlib 3.8.3 instead of 3.9.*. Has been driving me crazy for a couple weeks. So, try setting up a virtual environment in VSCode with matplotlib 3.8.3 and switching your interpreter to 3.11.9 in that environment.

thank you :) I changed the version and it was fixed.

this is crazy! any solution for python 3.12.5?

Is this a known issue? I was curious about the final solution

thank you, matplotlib version 3.8.3 works for me and my python version is 3.10.15 in case the problem relates with the python version.

Thanks, this helped a bunch. I was able to get matplotlib 3.8.2, 3.8.3, and 3.8.4 and Python 3.12 working together to plot in the debugger.
The problem exists for me with 3.9.* and python 3.12 and python 3.13.0
I was not able to get 3.8.* and python 3.13.0 to install.
The problem exists for me with at least 3.9.2 and python 3.13.0
even after bypassing the tcl error per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29320039/trying-to-use-tkinter-throws-tcl-error-cant-find-a-usable-init-tcl
So it definitely looks like a matplotlib 3.9 issue not a python 3.12 issue.

Clarification, works for me with both Python 3.12.0 and 3.12.7 but did not try the versions in the middle.
