# How to get JSON document as user input in python

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo, database

I am using mongoDB with python . I want user to enter a document in the JSON format  so that i can insert that into some collection in my db .How can this be done ?

Comment: Can i do that just by using the command prompt ? I mean the user will enter something like this  { name:"joe", age:19,hobby:"table tennis"} and it is taken into a variable .

Comment: You could. Use `raw_input` in Python 2 or `input` in Python 3, and then run the string through a JSON parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
#read string input 
dataone= raw_input()  
m=json.loads(dataone)
print (m["attribute name in double quotes "])
```

if the user enters this string {"name":"joe","age":18,"hobby":"singing"} 
the m["name"] will give the output joe.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in this similar question, [Choosing a file in Python with simple Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-with-simple-dialog) :

```
from Tkinter import Tk  
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename  

Tk().withdraw() # we don't want a full GUI, so keep the root window from appearing  
filename = askopenfilename() # show an "Open" dialog box and return the path to the selected file  
print(filename)
```