# Open file from windows file dialog with python automatically

Tags: python, windows, dialog, automated-tests, ui-automation

I do automated testing and get a file dialog. I want to choose a file from the windows open file dialog with python or selenium.

NOTE: The dialog is given by an other program. I don't want to create it with Tkinter.

The Window looks like:

[image: THIS].

How to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Choosing a file in Python with simple Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-with-simple-dialog)

Comment: @Alvin Please see the note.

Comment: Selenium will not help you. Have you considered [tag:AutoIt], [tag:Sikuli], [tag:RobotFramework].

Comment: Are you wanting to select a file at random, iterate through all of them, or select a particular file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider using the [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io/) package. It has a very natural syntax to automate any GUI programs.

[image]

Code example, opening a file in notepad. Note that the syntax is locale dependent (it uses the visible window titles / control labels in your GUI program):

```
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application().start_('notepad.exe')
app.Notepad.MenuSelect('File->Open')
# app.[window title].[control name]...
app.Open.Edit.SetText('filename.txt')
app.Open.Open.Click()
```

Comment: I would add some piece of code from [SaveFromFirefox.py example](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/blob/master/examples/SaveFromFirefox.py) to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use ctypes library.

Consider this code:

```
import ctypes

EnumWindows = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
EnumWindowsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
SendMessage = ctypes.windll.user32.SendMessageW
IsWindowVisible = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowVisible

def foreach_window(hwnd, lParam):
    if IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
        buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
        GetWindowText(hwnd, buff, length + 1)

        if(buff.value == "Choose File to Upload"): #This is the window label
            SendMessage(hwnd, 0x0100, 0x09, 0x00000001 )
    return True

EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc(foreach_window), 0)
```

You loop on every open window, and you send a key stroke to the one you choose.

The [SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) function gets 4 params: the window hendler (`hwnd`), The phisical key to send - [WM_KEYDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280(v=VS.85).aspx) (0x0100), The [virtual-key code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) of `tab` (`0x09`) and the `repeat count, scan code, extended-key flag, context code, previous key-state flag, and transition-state flag` in the 4th argument.

You can also send key up, key down, chars, returns and etc...
Use the documentation for help.

I used this as a reference: [Win32 Python: Getting all window titles](https://sjohannes.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/win32-python-getting-all-window-titles/)

Good luck!

Comment: Do you also can describe how to click on the first file? How do you get the element name? Thanks!