# How can I only accept certain file with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'd like to accept certain file, `config.cfg`, in tkinter `askopenfilename` dialog and here is my code.

```py
mod_config_path = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=None, 
                                                     title="Select config.cfg file", 
                                                     initialdir=steamapps, 
                                                     filetypes=[("config.cfg", "config.cfg")])
```

The problem is, `filetypes=[("config.cfg", "config.cfg")]` doesn't do what I meant to do.

I wanted to accept only `config.cfg` file, not `misc_config.cfg` or `otherconfig.cfg` that ends with `config.cfg`. But as shown below, it accepts `*config.cfg` file and `misc_config.cfg` file is also shown in the image.

[image]

So, what I want to do is, removing `*` in `*config.cfg` so that it only accepts `config.cfg` file.

I couldn't find any related answers around the internet and this is so disappointing...

Comment: Is this possible? I think tkinter adds an additional `*` on first of whatever extension you give there. Maybe leave it like that and then use python to verify that the file selected is just `config.cfg` and not `somethingconfig.cfg`.

Comment: It seems to be an OS dependent behavior. I am using Linux and the provided code does exactly what is wanted: I see only "config.cfg", and not "misc_config.cfg" or "otherconfig.cfg"

Comment: @j_4321 I guess you are right. *On the Unix and Macintosh platforms, extensions are matched using glob-style pattern matching. On the Windows platform, extensions are matched by the underlying operating system.* [Source](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/getOpenFile.htm#M10)

Comment: You could consider to use `ctypes` and try to catch the [FileOK_Event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37214623/13629335) but this seems to be too much work for me. If you just want to accept a special file, why dont you like to grap it programatically instead of a users choice?

Comment: Just for [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filter?view=net-5.0) MS docs dosent discuss such a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize my comments as an answer:

The [official docs of tcl](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/getOpenFile.htm#M10) for `tk` says:

> On the Unix and Macintosh platforms, extensions are matched using glob-style pattern matching. On the Windows platform, extensions are matched by the underlying operating system.

So if you're under windows, either you write your own *FileDialog* or you try to catch the [FileOK Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.filedialog.fileok?view=net-5.0) via `ctypes` and trigger a virtual event.

Alternatively you can follow @CoolCloud advice and verify file after the dialog.