# Making A simple GUI program in Sypder IDE on Anaconda

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, anaconda, window

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-with-simple-dialog) to write a simple gui program in my Spyder IDE on anaconda environment.I am using python 3.7. I used below  code :

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw() 
filename = askopenfilename() 
print(filename)
```

and

```
import easygui
print easygui.fileopenbox()
```

Both of the code seems to run indefinitely and doesn't open any window. Am i missing something? Is it even possible to make a gui program on anaconda environment?

Comment: do you get error ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: There is no error. Program is just running indefinitely

Comment: you could put `print()` between instructions to see which one stops code.

Comment: it should run in Anaconda the same way as in normal Python.

Comment: Use [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/7414759) as starting point.