# Why can't I change the current working directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am trying to create my first python program that deletes any empty directories within `d:\source`. It appears I can't even enter the directory with my current skills:

```
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir("D:\\SOURCE")
os.getcwd()
```

All I get is...

```
D:\CODING\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/CODING/tester.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

It seems it has not changed the working dir, how do I verify that? Why won't it display the results/errors for the `os.chdir("D:\\SOURCE")` or the second `os.getcwd()` command at all?

Comment: None of those commands output anything. try: `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: Closing as no repro.

Comment: It won't change the working directory of your shell if that is what you were expecting. Only the working directory subsequently in your script (as you should see if you print it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chances are your program indeed changes the directory. But you cannot see this:

- A mere `os.getcwd()` won't do anything visible: it retrieves the current working directory and discards it. Instead, you should do `print(os.getcwd())`
- Changing the current working directory only affects the current process (i. e., the Python program), but not its parent (the command prompt). So your command prompt keeps its cwd and doesn't inherit the one from the called program.

Comment: What would `os.chdir("D:\\SOURCE")` look like with added security? Like if directory change fails then do not continue.

Comment: @Bricktop Let's try it: `>>> os.chdir("doesn't exist")` leads to an exception `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "doesn't exist"`. So you surround it with `try:` and `except OSError, e:` and check the properties of `e`.

Comment: I understand all except the `e:` and `e` properties part but I got the conditions to work. Is it possible to just launch a directory chooser window for a missing directory?

Comment: @Bricktop Well, essentially that's basic [exception handling](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) which you'd have to look up. Of course it is possible to launch a chooser dialog: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-with-simple-dialog).

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the result.

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
os.chdir("D:\\SOURCE")
print(os.getcwd())
```

Answer (score 1):

os.chdir() *doesn't return any value*. It will just change the directory. As suggested in other answers you can print/output the current directory using

```
os.chdir("D:\\SOURCE") 
print(os.getcwd())
```