# How can I write some code that ask to user to load a file

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm building a tool for the company where I work and I've built a program that returns different statistics from any csv file, of course with an specific data structure. Now, my issue is that I don't know how to do is to request the user to upload a file. 
In order to create this program I've been using as practice mode,

```
this: df = pd.read_csv('',delimiter=';', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: how do you run it ? In console/terminal? In some GUI ? In Jupyter notebook ? As web page ? They need different method to get path to file or url. If you run in console/terminal then you have `filename = input()`

Comment: hello Nico welcome to SO. If you're looking for a GUI, go here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-with-simple-dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need some basic ui that the user can interact so they can select a file, you may want to consider the `easygui` module.

Or if you don't want to install a new module, just use `tkinter` built in.

Try this:

```
from tkinter import *
frome tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import pandas as pd

Tk().withdraw()
print("Please select a csv file to load") 
file = askopenfilename()
df = pd.read_csv(file, header = 0)
```

Hope this helps :)) . Check out the `easygui` module too. The documentation is brief so you can get a hang of it after a few tries.