# Specify file download location using PyDrive?

Tags: python, pydrive

I'm currently trying to download a file from Google Drive using PyDrive, but am only able to download the file to the same location as my Python program. Is there a way to specify the file's download location? This is how I am downloading files currently.

```
    if file1['title'] == file_name:
      file2 = drive.CreateFile({'id': file1['id']})
      print('Downloading file %s from Google Drive' % file2['title']) 
      file2.GetContentFile(file_name)  # Save Drive file as a local file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
if file1['title'] == file_name:
      location = "Path/where/you/want/to/save/"
      """
      if you are in linux and want to save it to documents try following
      location = "~/Documents/"
      the last forward slash i.e. '/' is important
      """

      full_path = location + file_name

      file2 = drive.CreateFile({'id': file1['id']})
      print('Downloading file %s from Google Drive' % file2['title']) 
      file2.GetContentFile(full_path)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this should suffice as an alternative, but would it also be possible to prompt the file explorer to load and use the GUI to specify a download location?

Comment: @ancient for that you need a GUI package for python like [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html). You can see following question for getting started on your requirement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-with-simple-dialog