# Making single EXE file from Python Script

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I am writing a script that gets data from advertising platform through request and pushes it to google sheets.
Right now everything works. But I need to know how to convert this into a exe file. I am using pyinstaller.

**My issue is I have Key files that needs to be included in the script to work (for authorization). After creating the exe file, the exe program doesnt work anymore because of the missing dependency file.**

Comment: How did you "include" the file ? I would read a fixed path on the network since it seems to be a corporate problem...  other option : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-with-simple-dialog

Comment: Please check the answer here - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63295487/2094351)

Comment: It worked. Thanks @RatneshKushwaha. Thanks to you too Mansuetus :)