# Create list of files of a Directory and select multiple files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, drop-down-menu, easygui

How do I create a list box with all the available files in a directory and allow the user to select files to be opened. I can create a list of files in a Directory using easygui. This list should be presented to the user to select the files. These are csv files and I will load the selected files in to different dataframes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choosing a file in Python with simple Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-with-simple-dialog)

Comment: The only change you'd have to make is changing `Tkinter` to `tkinter` (lowercase T). You can set the initial directory using `askopenfilename(initialdir=the_directory)`