# Import a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, select, import

I'm trying to import a CSV file of my choice (by selecting it) but in python's csv libraries I can't find a function that allows me to open a choice path without having to go through pyton's prompt.
Has anyone managed to open a Windows window for file selection? Thx

Comment: first you want to have a window to select a file, you should use tkinter to be able to do that check here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579568/choosing-a-file-in-python-with-simple-dialog] then use pandas to open it

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

file = pd.read_csv('path to your file', sep='your separator')
```